# Sending Email Template weekly with APEX

Tags: salesforce, apex

@sfdcfox
I have a specific email template that I want to send to clients on weekly basis from Salesforce.
The email must be sent to all customers according to the following:
1 - Customer ID NOT BLANK 
2 - Specific day of the week and time of the day.with respect to time zone.

Can you please help with step by step code?

​​​​​​​Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So this the time zone thing makes this trickier.

- Create an object that holds the transaction, let's call it `ClientEmail`

  - Store the record Id on a field such as `Client__c`
  - Store the Timestamp, in GMT from the locale of the client, of the datetime the email is available to send, `Available Date Time`
  - Add a boolean field, `Sent__c`
- Write your logic to gather the appropriate records in an Apex Class `ClientEmailController`.

  - SOQL Query should be similar to this format: `[SELECT Id,(SELECT Id,AvailableDateTime__c,Sent__c FROM ClientEmails__r WHERE Sent__c = false) FROM **Your Object** ]`
  - Iterate through that and if `ClientEmails__r.isEmpty() == true`, create a ClientEmail record with the appropriate time stamp.
  - If `ClientEmails__r.isEmpty() == false`, pass over the record.
- On another method, use a SOQL query, such as `[SELECT Id,Client__c,AvailableDateTime__c,Sent__c FROM ClientEmail__c WHERE AvailableDateTime__c = TODAY AND Sent__c = false]`, to gather all the records that are available today. Iterate through them and check if the GMT Datetime `> System.now()`. If they are, add them to a `List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>` and add the logic in to add them to the email template. Following sending that list of emails, update the records to `Sent__c = true`, update records.
- Create a Apex Class     `ClientEmailQueueable`. From there, implement `Queueable` and call your methods send method on `ClientEmailController` to gather and send emails.
- Then, in     `ClientEmailSchedulable`, implement `Schedulable` and call `System.enqueueJob(new ClientEmailQueueable());`

Make sure you have the job scheduled every hour during business hours.

It will be a fair amount of code, so I'm going to leave that to you, but your metadata structure is as follows:

- Custom Object: Client Email (`ClientEmail__c`)

  - Field: Client (`Client__c`) Master-Detail
  - Field: Available Date Time (`AvailableDateTime__c`) Datetime
  - Field: Sent (`Sent__c`) Checkbox/Boolean
- Apex Class    `ClientEmailController`

  - Create initial records methods
  - Gather and Send emails
- Apex Class:     `ClientEmailQueueable` `implements Queueable`

  - Call the     `Gather and Send Emails` method from here
- Apex Class:     `ClientEmailSchedulable` `implements Schedulable`

  - Call the     `ClientEmailQueueable` class from here

[SOQL Date References](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

[Apex Queueable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm)

[Apex Schedulable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm)

[Messaging Namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_classes_outbound_single)

Comment: Thank you for your great contribution. I am trying to do this myself since our developer is sick and won't be back for a while.
Given my limited knowledge in Apex coding, I wont be able to write this myself.
Can this whole process be implemented with Process Builder?

Comment: Hmmm, you could possibly do it via scheduled actions. You would unfortunately lose the luxury of having the email transaction records, but here is what I would try.

- On your Client record, add a few fields:
   1. `Last Email Datetime`; LastEmailDatetime; Datetime
   2. `Next Scheduled Email`; NextScheduledEmail; Datetime
   3. `Email frequency (Days)`; EmailFrequency; Datetime
- Evaluate the criteria on update of a record and utilize `Scheduled Actions` to Send the email based on the LastEmailDatetime + EmailFrequency, add an additional action to update the LastEmailDatetime

Comment: Thank you - Let me try your strategy and I will revert back